# What's the recommended way to open an OSX file package in PHP?

Tags: php, macos, file

I am talking about this thing:

[image]

Because a file package is just a container for folders and file, it should be easy to open it and list its content with PHP. However, looking at the documentation, I haven't found a nice way to do it so far.

Is there a recommended function to use in this case?

Comment: What is an "OS X file package"?

Comment: @Joni There you go: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_%28OS_X%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Wikipedia page:

> a package is a file system directory

If that is the case, you read it using the directory functions: opendir, readdir, scandir, glob.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I was probably just overthinking things :)